# Proton Fusion not instantiating Network Runner in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I am trying to make a multiplayer game with Proton Fusion in Unity. But it doesn't instantiate the Network Runner prefab. I have correctly referenced the prefab. Please help. I have tried many things to try and solve this but they dont work

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Fusion;
using Fusion.Sockets;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

public class NetworkRunningHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NetworkRunner NetworkRunnerPrefab;

    async void Start()
    {
        // Instantiate the NetworkRunnerPrefab
        GameObject runnerObject = Instantiate(NetworkRunnerPrefab.gameObject);
        runnerObject.name = "Network Runner";

        // Get the NetworkRunner component
        NetworkRunner networkRunner = runnerObject.GetComponent<NetworkRunner>();
        Debug.Log(runnerObject.gameObject.name);
        // Initialize the network runner asynchronously
        await InitializeNetworkRunner(networkRunner, GameMode.AutoHostOrClient, NetAddress.Any(), SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, null);

        Debug.Log("Server NetworkRunner has started.");
    }

    protected virtual async Task InitializeNetworkRunner(NetworkRunner runner, GameMode mode, NetAddress address, SceneRef scene, Action<NetworkRunner> initialized)
    {
        var sceneManager = runner.GetComponent<INetworkSceneManager>();
        if (sceneManager == null)
        {
            sceneManager = runner.gameObject.AddComponent<NetworkSceneManagerDefault>();
        }
        runner.ProvideInput = true;

        await runner.StartGame(new StartGameArgs
        {
            GameMode = mode,
            Address = address,
            Scene = scene,
            SessionName = "Chunky Monkey Racer",
            Initialized = initialized,
            SceneManager = sceneManager
        });
    }
}
```